# How add link address before the IP address in php form

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to post user IP address with link for tracking IP location, I have the below php code. I want to include user IP in the hyperlink link this `http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/108.44.33.225`

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "email@example.com";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $subject = "Email IP submission as link";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message .= "IP Address:" <a href="http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/. $ip .">. $ip</a>";

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you ";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct this line:

```
$message .= "IP Address: <a href='http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/". $ip ."'>". $ip."</a>";
```

or you can try

```
$message .= "IP Address: <a href='http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/$ip'>$ip</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a concatenation issue with your code, Try this,

```
$message .= "IP Address: <a href='http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/".$ip."'>$ip</a>";
```

instead of

```
$message .= "IP Address:" <a href="http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/. $ip .">. $ip</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks but link not comes with ip. I got only <a href="http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/"> like this. Any solution.